# Cannot make a call to Page WebMethod using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-2.0, webmethod

I am currently trying to develop a chat applicaiton in asp.net2.0 and requires me to make a call to **`aspx Page Webmethod`**.My issue is that i cannot make a call to the page webmethod.

Not showing any  message in error console of ff,so cannot findout where i have gone wrong.There is no issue while making a  call  webservice.

Heres the code i have writtern

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSend").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"{}",
      url:"Chat.aspx/GetTime",
      contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(msg){
        alert(msg.d);
      },
      error:function(msg){
        alert(msg.d);
      }
   });

  });

});
```

This is my **chat.aspx** page.The **GetTime** function is not getting called?Is the issue with the url ??

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string GetTime()
{
   return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is it even trying to post?  Do you have firebug?  If so, is there any activity in the Net tab of firebug?  How about fiddler - any activity?  If you put a breakpoint in the WebMethod does it get hit?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the webmethod and tested it,the breakpoint is not getting hit.Interesting fact is that when i  put the same code in webservice im getting the result correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I would look at are:

1.) I'm wasn't sure that ASP.NET 2.0 could use the JSON AJAX stuff. I thought that came about in 3.5, but may be thinking of the ASP.NET AJAX implementation instead of jQuery's. See: [Jquery's Ajax Property For Asp.Net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292308/jquerys-ajax-property-for-asp-net-2-0), specifically:

> You need to add this attribute to your webserver class

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

> and this attribute to your functions

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

2.) You may want to check to see if the version of jQuery AJAX you are using is compatible with ASP.NET 2.0. I remember there being an issue there and needing to use older versions of jQuery (like 1.3) See: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-not-working-for-asp-net-2-0-7-5-2011

3.) This may be a long shot but is your page called Chat.aspx, or chat.aspx? Javascript capitalization matters (O;

Long shots, all of them, so good luck (:

[EDIT] Was just rereading the question and another idea popped in: Is the button from your .ASPX page? The reason I ask is because it's possible that when it's getting rendered on the page your button is no longer 'ID="btnSend"' but instead 'ID="ctl_btnSend_0897234h15807"' or so. If you have attached your jQuery to find '#btnSend' there's a chance that it's not the same ID in the DOM anymore.

Hoping that helps![/EDIT]

Comment: 1.I have faced the same issue earlier and installed asp.net3.5 which solved the issue of using jquery ajax in asp.net2.0.When i write the above code in webservice it is showing the desired result.                                                             2.Since i am getting call to webservices correctly i dont think there is an issue with jquery version                                                                                                                                 3.I've also check the capitilization and i've given it correctly